# Gstreamer 1.0 video from camera too slow

Tags: gstreamer

I'm a beginner in Gstreamer and encountered an issue that I'm not able to figure out:
I use these two commands:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! autovideosink

gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! autovideosink
```

The 1.0 version displays the video with 1 frame per second, while the 0.10 version displays a smooth video (not sure about exact frame rate).

I'd like to have the same smooth video with gstreamer 1.0, can you help me figure out the exact syntax? I guess I'm missing some parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a few more googling gave me the answer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1' ! autovideosink
```

That provides a smooth video with 1.0.